# Finding general term of given sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a sequence follows a rule :

$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ for $n\geq3$

$a_1$ and $a_2$ are constants.

I tried finding via method of difference then i found that its difference is also coming out to be same sequence. This is the only method i know of finding general term.

So is there any more method of finding general term.

Comment: Is $$a_0$$ and $$a_1$$ given?

Comment: Have you heard of the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: nope. Actually this was the relation which came in a question of finding the way to place n places with heads such that there are no consecutive heads

Comment: Well look it up.

Comment: Read it but this is far beyond my current syllabus. I'm undergraduate. Haven't appeared for college yet.

Comment: Can anyone enlighten me without using the Fibonacci sequence if not possible then provide me the solution so that i can try to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Make the ansatz $$a_n=q^n$$ you will get $$q^n=q^{n-1}+q^{n-2}$$

Comment: I didn't get that

Comment: Why this question has been downvoted..

Comment: Ok i will try again with your hint

Comment: Can you proceed till end. Cuz I don't hace any knowledge about Fibonacci sequence nor i have read any related concepts.